# Compiling through latexmk on two machines (in a shared Dropbox folder): can I avoid the conflict files?

Tags: latexmk

### Question: compiling in `nonstopmode` in a shared folder ==> how to avoid the conflict files?

I am used to running latexmk in `nonstopmode` and often forget to stop it when I switch over to a new machine. As the document that I keep editing is hosted on Nutstore (a Chinese equivalent to Dropbox), two latexmk processes both running in `nonstopmode` shall create a lot of conflict files.

Is there a *hidden* setting of latexmk that can "detect" if there is another latexmk process that is also running in `nonstopmode`? Currently, I am compiling my tex documents using the following parameters:

`latexmk.pl -pvc -pdf --synctex=-1 -src-specials -silent -time -interaction=nonstopmode filename.tex`

I am looking for a set of specifications that can compile in `nonstopmode`, yet will only start compiling if  there is not an ongoing compilation process that is writing to the same directory. I can imagine dropping a `project.latexmain.lock` file deliberately into the working directory shall do the trick.

### Detailed info of my setting:

I am using two Windows machines with the same username. And, I am running `latexmk` via Git-Bash, through [ConEMU](https://conemu.github.io/) (a console emulator). For now, I have defined "start-up tasks" so that whenever I start ConEMU, my list of active documents (on-going projects, research journals and notes) are "loaded" (compiled in `nonstopmode`).

Compiler-wise, I am using MikTex.

Comment: Why don't you use a softlink to the TeX file on dropbox, and compile in a local folder?

Comment: Latexmk maintainer here: There's nothing in the current latexmk that does this.  I'll take this question as a feature request. (I've got caught by the same problem myself, with two instance of latexmk on the same machine.)   There can be interesting problems because of delays between creation of the lock file on the Dropbox folder on one computer and its creation on another.  But something along these lines is probably better than nothing.

Comment: @marmot The use of a softlink from a compilation directory to the Dropbox folder is indeed one way of solving the problem.  But it is often easier to work directly in the Dropbox folder, especially when the project has large numbers of files, especially graphics files generated by custom dependencies.

Comment: @llinfeng The problem is actually not specific to nonstopmode. In any latex mode, I've found problems with files generated from one instance of latexmk being trampled on from another instance. Nonstopmode does make the problem worse.

Comment: @JohnCollins Well, I've been doing this for years, and of course I also put softlinks to the included files. I find this much more convenient than cleaning up the junk files from my collaborators and receiving messages from dropbox that someone has changed something, which then turns out to be an aux file.

Comment: @marmot, thank you for your suggestion on the "soft link". Are you using `*NIX` system? Windows OS seems to have an equivalent "Symbolic link" thing, but it appears to be less useful: I think making the contents of a folder accessible through symbolic link means one need to move *ALL* the content of such folder out of the Dropbox (project) folder. Thus, in order to avoid those `*.aux` updates, the main `*.tex` file may need to be nested in its own `Project\Master` folder, thus getting ready for *outsourcing*. Is this your practice?

Comment: @marmot (continued). So far, all my `master.tex` is stored in the root folder of the project; and employing a "soft link" (or Symbolic link) pointing to a local directory may demand quite a bit: at minimum, to reorder all the `\input` addresses that were specified relatively. (Yet, I am not confident if my "forward-jumping" and "backward-jumping" should still work after I reorder the project directories.) Please correct me if I am getting the "soft link" (or "symbolic link") wrong.

Comment: No. I simply type in my local folder `ln -s ~/Dropbox/WhateverFolder/FreakyFile.tex`, and the same for figures. This works for linux and MacOS. I have abandoned windows in the last Millenium and never regretted that step. But I think it should be possible to soft link single files there, too.

Comment: I don't see why you can't rebuild the same folder structure in your local folder. And if these are pure input folders, you could just link them. That should be fine as long as you do not `\include` the files, in which case `.aux` files will be generated.

Comment: @JohnCollins, thanks a lot for accepting this rough question as a feature request. I have not yet reproduced conflict files with running two separate sessions of `latexmk`; and yes:`nonstopmode` shall "help" with generating conflicts. For the "*.lock` file, what I had in mind is something specific to the compiler (`latexmk`). So, it may be named as `*.latexmklock` or so. This shall prevent potential conflicts with those hidden syncing rules of Dropbox (or Nutstore).

Comment: @marmot Thank you for pointing out the `ln -s` command on `*NIX`, and that these links should be working for files! I have found a Windows equivalent: `mklink`. Also, to have it up and running, as you have suggested, I have to make such "soft link" for all the files that I have `\input`-ed. Will post an answer to answer my own question below.

Answer (score 2):

## Tentative solution: soft link (or `mklink` in Windows)

As [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) has suggested, one could pick any local folder s/he would like, and have all the compilations happening in this local folder. Here goes a few clarifications that helped me understood the scenario:

- First, such *soft link* can be constructed for **files**: thus, by issuing the following command in Windows, there is a two-way "sync" taking place between the Target and the Origin.

  `mklink address_for_target.txt address_for_Origin.txt`
- As it appears to me, *soft link* creates a "physical copy" of the Origin file, by which I mean: I can "see" the same file in the target location. And, editing either file w.r.t. to its "true location" shall update the contents in the other location.
- To handle picture-imports, one can create *soft link* for folders(directories) as well.
- Lastly, to make backward and forward search/jumping happen, it helps to create a *soft link* for the `project_main.tex.latexmain`. (My Tex editing environment: Windows OS + GVim + `latexmk` (through ConEMU) + MikTeX Distribution)

### Concrete steps (on Windows):

1. Find a local folder (in my case: `D:\build` for testing purpose`;
2. Create 'soft link' using `mklink D:\build\main_project.tex C:\project\main_projeect.tex`. (And, *repeat* such `mklink` command for all `*.tex` files that are sourced through `\input{}` function, and for `project.latexmain`.) A batch file my be helpful (and here is my demo: [mklink.bat](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DeAyRSIQoPimBhjg0kA)).
3. Once all the "soft links" are constructed, editing files in the target directory works; and compilation runs as well.

### Heads up for update

Yet, creating such mirrors for files is completely new to me, and seems would take me a lot more time to integrate into my workflow.

[John Collins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8495/john-collins), our beloved Latexmk maintainer, has accepted the question as a feature request. He said in his comment that conflict files can also be generated through running two `latexmk` processes on the same computer. File-syncing through Dropbox is just a special case of such conflict. Awaiting for an update :)